# Any possiblilities that objects may be disposed earlier?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader

Is there any chance that `fileStream` object will likely be destroyed before its call to the `Close` method as below?

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(xxx);
StreamReader txtReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

curLog = txtReader.ReadToEnd();

txtReader.Close();
fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Yes, the txtReader.Close() call will also close the fileStream :)  Otherwise, no.

Comment: So this is a bug then ? will an exception be thrown ?

Comment: It is entirely by design.  No exception is thrown.  Having to guess at the reason for this question is pretty tiresome btw.

Comment: @user3462253 Be aware that [one StreamReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg712952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lets you control whether it closes the underlying stream itself (in case you ever need such behaviour)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any chance that fileStream object will likely be destroyed
>   before its call to the Close method as below?

No.

But you should never write code like that. You should always wrap IDisposable resources in `using` statements to ensure that they will be disposed even if an exception is thrown and that you won't be leaking handles.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(xxx))
using (StreamReader txtReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    curLog = txtReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But for the purpose of this specific example you could simply use the [`ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string curLog = File.ReadAllText(xxx);
```

Comment: Exactly, I was just adding this.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any chance that it is closed before that. And i would recommend using it like this

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(xxx);
using (StreamReader txtReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
            curLog = txtReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Since StreamReader closes the underlying stream by default, you don't need the outer using.